# intellij idea me esta subiendo todos los archivos a un repositorio de github

Tags: java, spring-boot, git, intellij-idea

estoy presentando el problema de que intellij idea me sube todos los proyectos a un repositorio que no conozco de github, y cada vez que creo un nuevo proyecto tambien los sube,estoy aprendiendo a usar git por lo cual presento este problema y no se como solucionarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puede ser que tengas vinculado un repositorio de gitHub en tus ajustes, en  IntelliJ, ve a File -> Settings -> Version control -> GitHub... Ahí debería de aparecerte esa cuenta vinculada, seleccionala y eliminala con el -, te recomiendo usar terminal de gitBash para el tema git/gitHub.
Un saludo

Comment: gracias me ayudaste